# Can an index be added to a PRIMARY with a null key?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a query that takes a long time to return, roughly 12-15 seconds, which I'd like to optimize.  The query below is the result of running the original query with `SHOW WARNINGS`.  If I run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` on this query (and it's predecessor) it shows me that a PRIMARY select_type is derived, has null possible keys, null key, null key_len, and 314883 rows (see below).

Here's my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `steps`.`TestStepName` AS `TestStepName`
    ,`test`.`measurements`.`MeasurementName` AS `MeasurementName`
FROM `test`.`measurements`
JOIN (
    SELECT `test`.`teststeps`.`TestSteps_ID` AS `TestSteps_ID`
        ,`test`.`teststeps`.`TestStepName` AS `TestStepName`
    FROM `test`.`teststeps`
    JOIN (
        SELECT `dutdataassembly`.`AssyInTest` AS `AssyInTest`
            ,`test`.`testinformation`.`TestInformation_ID` AS `TestInformation_ID`
        FROM `test`.`testinformation`
        JOIN (
            SELECT `test`.`dutdata`.`AssyInTest` AS `AssyInTest`
                ,`test`.`events`.`Event_ID` AS `Event_ID`
            FROM `test`.`dutdata`
            JOIN `test`.`events`
            WHERE (
                    (`test`.`events`.`EventType_ID` = 7)
                    AND (`test`.`events`.`Event_ID` = `test`.`dutdata`.`Event_ID`)
                    AND (
                        `test`.`dutdata`.`AssyInTest` = '41528F'
                        )
                    )
            ) `dutdataassembly`
        WHERE (`test`.`testinformation`.`Event_ID` = `dutdataassembly`.`Event_ID`)
        ) `testinfo`
    WHERE (
            (`test`.`teststeps`.`TestInformation_TestInformation_ID` = `testinfo`.`TestInformation_ID`)
            AND (`test`.`teststeps`.`NumberOfMeasurements` > 0)
            )
    ) `steps`
WHERE (
        (`test`.`measurements`.`TestSteps_TestSteps_ID` = `steps`.`TestSteps_ID`)
        AND (`test`.`measurements`.`MeasurementName` <> '')
        )
ORDER BY `steps`.`TestStepName`
    ,`test`.`measurements`.`MeasurementName`
```

EXPLAIN statement:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, PRIMARY, <derived2>, ALL, , , , , 314883, 100.00, Using temporary; Using filesort
1, PRIMARY, measurements, ref, fk_Measurements_TestSteps1_idx,idx_Measurements,idx_measurementName,idx_justNames, fk_Measurements_TestSteps1_idx, 4, steps.TestSteps_ID, 1, 100.00, Using where
2, DERIVED, <derived3>, ALL, , , , , 16237, 100.00, 
2, DERIVED, teststeps, ref, fk_TestSteps_TestInformation1_idx,idx_testinformationid, fk_TestSteps_TestInformation1_idx, 4, testinfo.TestInformation_ID, 9, 100.00, Using where
3, DERIVED, <derived4>, ALL, , , , , 16237, 100.00, 
3, DERIVED, testinformation, ref, fk_TestInformation_Events1_idx, fk_TestInformation_Events1_idx, 4, dutdataassembly.Event_ID, 1, 100.00, Using index
4, DERIVED, dutdata, ref, fk_dutdata_Events1_idx,dutdata_index, dutdata_index, 138, , 33116, 100.00, Using where
4, DERIVED, events, eq_ref, PRIMARY,fk_Events_EventType1_idx, PRIMARY, 4, test.dutdata.Event_ID, 1, 100.00, Using where
```

The table `measurements` has hundreds of thousands of entries in it and has been indexed.  The table `teststeps` has an order of magnitude fewer entries and has also been indexed.

The desired result of this query is a one to many table where each teststep can have many measurements associated with it.

I hope that's enough information to go on.

Comment: You can't really "optimize" this query.  You need to throw it away and completely rewrite it without the `FROM ... JOIN (SELECT ...` derived tables, whose purpose is not obvious here.  You are materializing the innermost query into a temp table, and doing a full scan of it, repeatedly, almost completely defeating all of your indexes.  Using ANSI joins, expressed with `t1 JOIN t2 ON` instead of joining in `WHERE` would go a long way toward readability, and consider that `DISTINCT` is often, through not always, a red flag that says "I got more rows than I expected and I don't understand why."

Comment: Is refactoring the query something you can help me do?

Comment: `measurements` is not the problem; the subquery is.  How many rows are you expecting?  314883?  Or will the DISTINCT shrink that a lot?  If so, the perhaps the DISTINCT needs to be in one of the subqueries.  Also, please use the JOIN..ON syntax instead of having the ON in a WHERE clause.

Comment: When this particular query runs, there are 165 rows in the final results.  There can be multiple test steps of the same name for each of the measurements.  It can vary from 1:1 ( test step : measurement ) to 1:16 (16 is an arbitrary number chosen as the max number of measurements per test step).  Can you show an example of the JOIN...ON syntax?